# ASP.NET, Images, UpdatePanel iOS

Tags: ios, asp.net, updatepanel

I have developed a Web App that displays a live view of an HMI process.

Essentially it consists of master-detail solution. Within one of the detail pages is an image that refreshes every second on a timer tick. The image is displayed within a panel, itself inside an UpdatePanel. The updatepanel is explicitly refreshed on a timer tick (btw I've tried all variations/combinations of updatepanel properties without success).

On desktop Chrome, IE, Firefox, this solution works well. Sometimes, for some unknown reason, the page insists on doing a full refresh but overall the animation is smooth. Below is a screenshot of what the page looks like
[image: Normal Image]

When this app is viewed in Safari/Opera/Dolphin (build 5) (iOS 5 and 7), the results are very different. In between refreshes, the page is rendered minus the image and then finally with the image. The result is horrible shuddering of the page. The page in fact appears to be doing a full refresh (even the nav bar at the top resizes). The below image is what appears in between the update of the main image:

[image: No animation image here]

And when it's sorted itself out, the full page:

[image: Correctly rendered page]

Occasionally this behaviour occurs on Chrome/Firefox on the desktop versions - this was minimised by disabling hardware acceleration within the browsers. But for Safari, it happens **every** refresh and has become a serious, app-killer problem since the majority of intended users will be iPad/iPhone users.

I've searched for days for a solution, adding various things to web.config, Page PreInit etc, but with no luck.

This is some of what I've tried :

Web.Config

```html
 <browserCaps userAgentCacheKeyLength="256" />
```

Source Code:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.UserAgent != null && Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
        {
            this.ClientTarget = "uplevel";
        }
```

I've done some playing around with how the image is inserted into the page ( it's a Base64 jpg string). I thought there was a problem with the image, but cutting a long story short, I inserted instead a tiny standard project image (.jpg) with the url suffixed with a random number to prevent caching - and the problem **still** happened (i.e. a full refresh still occurred in between timer ticks). So it's not an issue with the base64 encoded string. I've also removed all other controls apart from the image and still I get the full page refresh and violent screen shudder.

This is driving me nuts. I've tried it on iOS5 and 7 and both have the same refresh problem. It's really quite serious, since this makes the app unusable on iPads/iPhones.

I hope someone can please help.

Thanks

Here's the aspx code of the Master Page:

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="PracticonWebMimic.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">

       
<%--    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">--%>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Practicon Factory Viewer</title>
    
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <meta http-equiv=”Page-Exit” content=”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Fade(duration=.5)” />

    
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
       <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/webkit.js" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Practicon Factory View</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" id="mimicList" visible="false"
                                 href="~/RestrictedAccess/MimicList.aspx">Views</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" id="mimicListArchive" visible="false"
                                 href="~/RestrictedAccess/MimicList.aspx?archive=<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>">Archive Views</a></li>
                       <!-- <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li> -->
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                              <!--  <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li> -->
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <p >Tip: For optimal viewing experience, please ensure you have <b>disabled</b> <i>Hardware Acceleration</i> in your browser's settings. <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/chrome/browser/desktop/">Google Chrome</a> is the recommended browser.</p>
             <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Practicon Factory <i>View</i></p>
                <asp:Label  id="lbError" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code for the detail page

```html
<%@ Page Title="Factory View" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MimicDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="PracticonWebMimic.MimicDetails" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="TimePicker" Namespace="MKB.TimePicker" TagPrefix="MKB" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

     <link href="/Content/PrBlueTable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
            prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
        });

        function InitializeRequest(sender, args) { }
        function EndRequest(sender, args) {
            // after update occur on UpdatePanel re-init the DatePicker 
            $('.ui-datepicker').datetimepicker({
                inline: true,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                showOn: 'focus',
                showButtonPanel : true,
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                nextText: ">>",
                prevText : "<<",
                timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            });
        }
</script>

    
       
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        if (typeof (Sys.Browser.WebKit) == "undefined") {
            Sys.Browser.WebKit = {};
        }
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("WebKit/") > -1) {
            Sys.Browser.agent = Sys.Browser.WebKit;
            Sys.Browser.version = parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.match(/WebKit\/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/)[1]);
            Sys.Browser.name = "WebKit";
        }
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

        prm.add_beginRequest(beginRequest);

        function beginRequest() {
            prm._scrollPosition = null;
        }

</script>


    <asp:FormView ID="mimicDetail" runat="server"
            ItemType="PracticonWebMimic.Models.Mimic" SelectMethod ="GetMimic"
            RenderOuterTable="false">

            <ItemTemplate>
                    <div>
                            <h2>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblActive_MimicDetails" runat="server"  Visible="true"/>

                                <%#:Item.MimicName %>


                            </h2>
                          
                           
                    </div>
                    <br />
                  <table>
                              <tr>  
                                    <td>
                                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMimic_MimicDetails" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTrigger="false">
                                                  <Triggers>

                                                            <%-- <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmrMimic_MimicDetails" EventName="Tick"/> --%>

                                                   </Triggers>

                                                 <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbConditionName_MimicDetails" runat="server" CssClass="btn-primary" Visible="False"/>
                                                          <asp:Panel ID="pnMimic" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 2px">

                                                                        
                                                                            <asp:image id="imMimic_MimicDetails" runat="server" />

                                                                            <h4><asp:Label  id="lbDirection_MimicDetails" runat="server" CssClass="btn-default"  Text=""></asp:Label> </h4>



                                                                           <%-- Action Buttons starts here ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --%>
                                                                        <asp:Table class="tbActionButtonBar"  runat="server"  CssClass="prTable">
                                                                                    <asp:TableRow >
                                                                                        <asp:TableCell>

                                                                                                <asp:Table class="tbActionButtonBar"  runat="server">

                                                                                                        <asp:TableRow >
                                                                                                                <asp:TableCell >
                                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnRestart_MimicDetails" runat="server" onclick="imgRestart_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Restart playback from beginning." />
                                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnStop_MimicDetails" runat="server"  onclick="imgStop_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Stop playback and show the LIVE Factory View." />
                                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnRewind_MimicDetails" runat="server"  onclick="imgRewind_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Rewind the animation" />
                                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnPlay_MimicDetails" runat="server" onclick="imgPlay_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Start playback of animation from current time." />
                                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnFForward_MimicDetails" runat="server" onclick="imgFForward_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Fast-forward through animation." />
                                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnPause_MimicDetails" runat="server" onclick="imgPause_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Pause playback of animation." />
                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                </asp:TableCell>

                                                                                                                <asp:TableCell> 
                                                                                                                      <asp:ImageButton id="btnTrends_MimicDetails" runat="server"  Width="50" ToolTip="Show the Trends for the current Factory View" />
                                                                                                                 </asp:TableCell>

                                                                                                                 <asp:TableCell>
                                                                                                                     <asp:ImageButton id="btnConditionMonitoring_MimicDetails" runat="server"  Width="50" ToolTip="View Condition Monitoring for this Factory View." />
                                                                                                                </asp:TableCell>
                                                                                            
                                                                                                                <asp:TableCell>
                                                                                                                            <h5><asp:Label ID="lbStatus_MimicDetails" runat="server"  CssClass="btn-default" Text=""></asp:Label></h5>
                                                                                                                </asp:TableCell>
                                                                                            
                                                                                                                 <asp:TableCell>
                                                                                                                            <h5><asp:Label ID="lbSession_MimicDetails" runat="server"  CssClass="btn-default" Text=""></asp:Label></h5>
                                                                                                                </asp:TableCell>

                                                                                                                <asp:TableCell>
                                                                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSession_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text="RESET" CssClass="btn btn-default" onclick="btnSession_MimicDetails_Click"> </asp:button>
                                                                                                                </asp:TableCell >


                                                                                                        </asp:TableRow>
                                                                                                </asp:Table>
                                                                                 </asp:TableCell >

                                                                           </asp:TableRow>

                                                                        </asp:Table>


                                                                         <%-- DateTime control starts here ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --%>


                                                                         <asp:Table  id="tbActionDateBar_MimicDetails" runat="server" CssClass="prBlueTable">

                                                                                        <asp:TableRow>

                                                                                                <asp:TableCell >
                                                                                                        <asp:Label Text="FROM   : " runat="server" id="lbFrom_MimicDetails"></asp:Label>
                                                                                                        <asp:TextBox type="text" id="txtStartDate_MimicDetails" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtStartDate_MimicDetails_TextChanged" />
                                                                                                        <asp:Label  id="lbFromDate_MimicDetails" runat="server"/>
                                                                                                </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                                                                                                            <asp:CheckBox Text="  End date? " runat="server" id="chkEndDate_MimicDetails" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkEnableEndDate_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
                                                                                                </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell >
                                                                                                            <asp:Label Text="TO    : " runat="server" ID ="lbTo_MimicDetails"></asp:Label>
                                                                                                </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                                                                                                            <asp:TextBox type="text" id="txtEndDate_MimicDetails" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtEndDate_MimicDetails_TextChanged"/>
                                                                                                            <asp:Label  id="lbEndDate_MimicDetails" runat="server"/>
                                                                                                </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                                                                                                            <asp:CheckBox Text="Auto-restart?" runat="server" id="chkAutoRewind_MimicDetails"  OnCheckedChanged="chkAutorewind_MimicDetails_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
                                                                                                </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table><asp:Timer ID="tmrMimic_MimicDetails" runat="server" Interval="1000"  OnTick="MimicTimer_Tick" ClientIDMode="AutoID"> </asp:Timer>
                                                                
                                          
                                                              <asp:Label ID="lbServiceResponse_MimicDetails" runat="server" CssClass="btn-default"  Text="" ></asp:Label><br /><asp:Label  id="lbRefreshRequested_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                              
                                                              <asp:Label  id="lbRefreshed_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                              
                                                              <br /><asp:Label ID="lbServiceAddress_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br/>
                                                              
                                                              <asp:Label ID="lbError_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                              
                                                              <asp:Label ID="lbSessionID_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>


                                                          </asp:Panel>


                                                 </ContentTemplate>


                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>

                                    </td>


                              </tr>

                  </table>


            </ItemTemplate>


    </asp:FormView>


</asp:Content>
```